# Should I use _self SelfLink for sub documents

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Building a document structure, let's imagine we have 2 kinds of documents: Person and Pet. Both can be a document on its own, and at the same time Pet can be in a Pets collection on Person.

If the subdocuments in the Pets collection is a simpler type, would it then be a good idea to include the SelfLink from the original Pet, if I at some point I needed to lookup the Original Pet document this is a subset of?

Is this the most effective way to lookup a document in CosmosDb, or should I just use its ID and a known document collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A self-link is a static addressable Uri for each resource within a database account and follows the Azure Cosmos DB resource model.
>   E.g. a self-link for a document could be `dbs/db_resourceid/colls/coll_resourceid/documents/doc_resourceid`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.resource.selflink?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Resource_SelfLink

The difference is rather limited when you look at the content of the `SelfLink`. It contains the `id`, `collection` and `database`. If you know the `id` and `collection`, you will probably be able to find the document effectively in either case since you can reconstruct the `SelfLink`.

My suggestion would be to use seperate fields and not the `SelfLink`. It is probably less engineering effort for future use cases. Reason being that it will allow you to do things like this:

- query more easily without having to construct a complex query link (e.g. by collectionId, or pet id)
- migrate data to a new database (updating your data will be a bit easier)

The difference is minimal however. I would only use a link if you are referencing a "more external resource" or you are spreading your data across many collections and need very efficient queries "by selflink".

Comment: I get the point and also sees some benefits in just using the ID of the doc. thanks for your input